# Why eventListeners does not work, but eventHandler is working?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a problem when i put eventListeners instead of eventHandlers i get more than one result in console working, when i use eventHandeler i do not i can just click once and i will get once working, no matter that after that i click more times on card, click was remove, but when i use eventListeners i click more times more times i will have working in my console the problem is that i am not deleting click from my card.

```
class Card{
    static allCards = [];
    constructor(imgSrc, cardSize){
        this.imgSrc = imgSrc;
        this.cardSize = cardSize;

        this.htmlElement = this.makeCard(imgSrc, cardSize);
    }

    makeCard(imgSrc, cardSize){

        let card = document.createElement("div");
        let back = document.createElement("div");
        let front = document.createElement("div");
        let img = document.createElement("img");

        img.src = imgSrc;

        card.classList.add("card");
        front.classList.add("card-front");
        back.classList.add("card-back");

        card.append(front)
        card.append(back)
        back.append(img);
        card.style.width  = cardSize;
        card.style.height = cardSize;

        /* GOOD BEHAVIOR
         card.onclick = this.flipCard.bind(this, card);
        */

        /* BAD BEHAVIOR 
            card.addEventListener("click", this.flipCard.bind(this, card));
        */

        Card.allCards.push(card);

        return card;
    }

    flipCard(card){
        console.log("working")
        card.classList.add("active");


        /* 
        card.onclick = null;
        */

        /* I USED BOTH CASES NONE OF THEM IS WORKING
        card.removeEventListener("click", this.flipCard)
        card.removeEventListener("click", this.flipCard.bind(this, card))
        
        */

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue is that the code is not passing the same listener function value to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` when trying to remove it. This is because `Function.prototype.bind` return a *different* function object each call. This issue has been asked about on SO before so I won't go into additional detail here.

A suggested solution for this particular case is to remove the `card` argument from `flipCard`, the additional `card` argument passed to `flipCard.bind`, and bind `flipCard` to the Card object in the class constructor - and simplify as much as possible in the process. Suggested changes to the Card class are as follows.

**`Constructor`**

```
constructor(imgSrc, cardSize){
    this.imgSrc = imgSrc;
    this.cardSize = cardSize;
    this.flipCard = this.flipCard.bind(this);
    this.htmlElement = this.makeCard(imgSrc, cardSize);
}
```

where `this.flipCard` on the right of the assignment refers to the prototypical class method, and on the left to a new enumerable own property of the Class instance.

**`flipCard` method**

```
flipCard( event){
    const card = this.htmlElement;
    card.classList.add("active");
    card.removeEventListener("click", this.flipCard)
}
```

where the `event` argument is documentary to show that the method is an event handler, and `htmlElement` is obtained from the `this` value.

**`makeCard`**

The commented out good and bad behavior adding of event handler to the `card` element can be removed entirely and replaced with

```js
card.addEventListener(this.flipCard);
```

Noting the bound version of `flipCard` is added to the instance object in the constructor before calling `makeCard`.